# Cuando paso como parametro `property` dentro de la funcion muestra `undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy tratando de que un grupo de cajas de texto o `input`, solo permitan numero, pero me he topado con un problema, y es que no reconoce `property` o `popertyName`, lo cual no me permite saber, si estoy escribiendo numero o letra, ya que solo quiero escribir números en dichos `input`

```
###dataPersonHouse.js

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

import '../styles/main.css';

class InputDataPerson extends Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            infoPersonHouse:{                
                year: "",
                anguloInclinacion:"",
                potenciaPanel:"",
                diasNoSoleados:""
            }
        };
        this.updateFields = this.updateFields.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Digite los siguientes datos</h3>
                <ul className="None-Style">

                    <li>
                        <input type="text"
                               placeholder="Posibles dias no soleados"
                               value={this.state.diasNoSoleados} 
                               onChange={this.updateFields}
                               name="dias"/>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="text" 
                               placeholder="Angulo de inclinacion"
                               value={this.state.anguloInclinacion}
                               onChange={this.updateFields}
                               name="angulo"/>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="text" 
                               placeholder="Potencia paneles solares"
                               value={this.state.potenciaPanel}
                               onChange={this.updateFields}
                               name="potencia"/>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <input type="text" 
                               placeholder="Año a obtener la informacion"
                               value={this.state.year}
                               onChange={this.updateFields}
                               name="year"/>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div> 
        );
    }


    updateFields(event, propertyName){

        console.log(event);
        console.log(propertyName);
        const dataHouse = {...this.state.infoPersonHouse};
        const numbers = /^[0-9\b]+$/;          
        dataHouse[propertyName] = event.target.value;
        this.setState({ dataHouse });

       if (dataHouse[property] == '' || numbers.test(dataHouse[property])) {
            this.setState({ dataHouse }); 
        } 

    } 

}

export default InputDataPerson;
```

#### Imagen

[image: error property]

En la imagen anterior expuesta, se puede observar el error, puse dos `console.log`, los cuales muestran el contenido de `event` y `property` cada que presiona una tecla.

Comment: Estás llamando a la función `updateFields` en el `onchange` pero nunca le estás pasando esos parámetros.

Comment: Podrías responder, te lo agradecería.

Comment: el onchange recibe event nada mas, el resto lo sacas por event.target

Answer (score 1):

Es porque no le estás pasando los parámetros dentro de la función `onChange`.

```
<input
  type="text"
  placeholder="Posibles dias no soleados"
  value={this.state.diasNoSoleados} 
  onChange={event => this.updateFields(event, "dias")}
  name="dias" />
```

Comment: el name también lo puede acceder por event.target.name

Comment: disculpa, me aparece esto, `warning.js:33 Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.`